# Changed display language & Thread.CurrentCulture is right but Thread.CurrentUICulture is wrong

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, multithreading, localization

I'm working on translating my WPF application to work in Chile.  I've got the localization stuff working.  The application has to work with the machine's culture settings so there's no need to add code to change the language on the fly.

I installed the Windows Spanish language pack (I'm running Windows 8.1).  I added Spanish as a second language.  When I switch to Spanish, my program is still in English!

I placed a breakpoint in the code & inspected the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` properties.  `CurrentCulture` is "es-CL" as I want, but `CurrentUICulture` is "es-ES".  This is wrong!  As there's no language resource file for "es-ES", my program is defaulting back to English.

How do I get the system to run with es-CL as the culture for both properties?  I assume I did something wrong in my set-up when I switched to Spanish . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we ended up doing to work around this was to rename our string resources for the es language only.  So the resource file is MyResource.es.dll, instead of MyResource.es-CL.dll.  This way, the difference in the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture properties won't matter.